# Matlab: Superimposing one array on another

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have an array A which has a size of 3x1x3 like this:

`A = zeros(3, 1, 3);`

What I would like to do is update this array with an array B of size 1x1x3 so suppose B contains 211 in the first layer, then 202 in the second layer and in the final layer it contains 185.

I am trying to find an operation in matlab such that A(1,1,1) = 211, A(1,1,2)=202 and A(1,1,3)=185.

I looked at linear indices but that didn't work out the way I wanted to. A for loop suffices but I was wondering if there was an inbuilt way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple matrix indexing:

```
A(1,1,:) = B;
```

Comment: Agh I was using A(1,1,3)=B; and was wondering why it wasnt working :(